# Meaning of more less?

Tags: word-usage

I heard it a few weeks ago, but I'm not sure whether it's correct to say, or not.
For instance, if I wanted to explain something similar like 'so-so'?

Can I reply 'more less' for the following question?
"Did you prepare for your exam?"
 - More less.
 (and assume, that I would like to say 'so-so'. )

Comment: The expression is *more or less.* Others include *not quite, not enough*, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The phrase you probably heard is [***more or less***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/more%20or%20less):

> to a varying or undetermined extent or degree :  somewhat <they were *more or less* willing to help>

Since the end of "more" has the same sound as "or," it's easy to mistakenly hear (or poorly articulate) the words "more or" as simply "more".

Comment: [I find it interesting how the Italian language already has a mechanism in place to deal with this very issue.](https://www.italki.com/question/26737)